# Create export PDF module for div with canvas and multiple div

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, phantomjs

I have a html page like this:

```
 <html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
   <title>charts</title>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/charts.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery   /1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#thebutton").click(function(){
          //execute phantomjs to save div id example to pdf
      });     
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="frame" class="graph2" style="position: relative; left: 0pt; top: 5pt; width: 500px; height: 415px;">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" height="415" width="500"></canvas>
            <div id="resultC10000" class="num" style="position: absolute; left: 120px; top: 195px;">4</div>
            <div id="resultC01000" class="num" style="position: absolute; left: 360px; top: 195px;">3</div>
            <div id="resultC00100" class="num num-empty" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -2200px;">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="button" id="thebutton" value="export"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

. I would create an export module to png but especially into pdf (a button or list to launch the export). For that I was thinking of using the plugin phantomjs and rasterize.js ( like Highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts#phantom_usage) but I do not know how to integrate and to use directly into my web page. Also, my main div contains a canvas but also a set of div containing text. I think we need to convert all of my div into canvas, to then convert it to pdf with the previous plugins.

can you give me some leads to convert div into pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using exactly the same tool as what you're using for PNGs: `phantomjs`.

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.paperSize = {
  format: "A4",
  orientation: "portrait",
  margin: {left:"2.5cm", right:"2.5cm", top:"1cm", bottom:"1cm"},
};
page.zoomFactor = 1;
// assume the file is local, so we don't handle status errors
page.open("http://your.url/here", function (status) {
   page.render("/path/to/your/pdf.pdf");
   phantom.exit();
});
```

Yes, it is really that easy. You can, obviously, restrict `render()` using the standard `phantom` calls. In reality, to print, all you need is:

- paper format/size defined
- a file ending as `.pdf` passed to `render()`.

Comment: Okay, but I do not know how to use it directly in my html page. I saw that you could use the command line but I want that clicking on a button you can save my main div.Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Tof: `phantomjs` is a server-side node module. What you'll need to do is to bind a route to trigger the process, and from there, return the path to the filename.

Comment: But I do not see how I can give my div to phantomjs.

Comment: @Tof: you can give it the HTML code for the entire page via AJAX, or you can re-render the page server-side, once again, using phantomjs.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like that:
`<input type="button" oneclick="functionExport()">` and `functionExport()` which allows to get my div and save it to PDF. But I do not know how to do my function Export.

Comment: @Tof: you will not be able to do this purely client-side, so get reading on AJAX. Your best solution is just to feed phantomjs your entire DOM and have it render + print + feed back the filename (hence my answer). The other option is through PHP, using html2pdf. Method is the same.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help. i will find more information about Ajax because i do not know it.